# Redirect http to https via .htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

I've seen a few questions like this on here, but no answer seems to work. I just can't seem to figure this out. Here is my code:

```
# enable basic rewriting

RewriteEngine on

# enable symbolic links
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Primary Domain - Force the use of "https"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Primary Domain - Force the use of "www"
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.org [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1 [r=301,nc]

# Primary Domain - .com to .org
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]

# Primary Domain - .net to .org
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So whenever I go to `www.example.org` or `http://www.example.org` it will NOT redirect. This is what is frustrating me. If I go to example.org or any of the other redirects, it works though. Am I setting this up wrong?

Also, where it says "HTTP_HOST", do I leave it as is? Like do I replace it with my http host?

Answer (score 1):

Amie if you want to force `www` and `https` both you can check for the absence of www. or check if `https` is **not** `On` then redirect. So either way it will redirect. example.

```
# Primary Domain - Force the use of "https" and www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Replace mydomain.org with your domain.

Then you can have a htaccess file like this. I took the last two rules and combined them so you have a smaller htaccess file.

```
# enable basic rewriting
RewriteEngine on

# enable symbolic links
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Primary Domain - Force the use of "https" and www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.org/$1 [R=301,L]

# Primary Domain - .com to .org Or .net to .org
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.(net|com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

> Also, where it says "HTTP_HOST", do I leave it as is? Like do I
>   replace it with my http host?

`%{HTTP_HOST}` is a variable that contains the host sent with Http headers from the browser. So if someone requests `http://mydomain.org/somepage.php` that variable `%{HTTP_HOST}` will contain `mydomain.org`. You don't change it. You can use it to match things or set conditions like in the rules. Hope that answers your question.